# 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'toDF' in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm trying to load an SVM file and convert it to a `DataFrame` so I can use the ML module (`Pipeline` ML) from Spark.
I've just installed a fresh Spark 1.5.0 on an Ubuntu 14.04 (no `spark-env.sh` configured).

My `my_script.py` is:

```
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local", "Teste Original")
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "/home/svm_capture").toDF()
```

and I'm running using:  `./spark-submit my_script.py`

And I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/fred-spark/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/pipeline_teste_original.py", line 34, in <module>
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "/home/fred-spark/svm_capture").toDF()
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'toDF'
```

What I can't understand is that if I run:

```
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "/home/svm_capture").toDF()
```

directly inside PySpark shell, it works.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`toDF` method is a monkey patch [executed inside `SparkSession` (`SQLContext` constructor in 1.x) constructor](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L43-L59) so to be able to use it you have to create a `SQLContext` (or `SparkSession`) first:

```
# SQLContext or HiveContext in Spark 1.x
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()

rdd = sc.parallelize([("a", 1)])
hasattr(rdd, "toDF")
## False

spark = SparkSession(sc)
hasattr(rdd, "toDF")
## True

rdd.toDF().show()
## +---+---+
## | _1| _2|
## +---+---+
## |  a|  1|
## +---+---+
```

Not to mention you need a `SQLContext` or `SparkSession` to work with `DataFrames` in the first place.

Comment: How can I tell MyPy that `toDF` exists and what its signature is?

Comment: This shows how much of a trash is PySpark with it's API, so obscure, impractical and workarounded

Comment: @IvánSánchez So use something else? `pyspark` actually totally rocks. Every library takes some effort to get going but man what benefits this one has

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have spark session too.

```
sc = SparkContext("local", "first app")
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```