# How do I order fields of my Row objects in Spark (Python)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm creating Row objects in Spark. I do not want my fields to be ordered alphabetically. However, if I do the following they are ordered alphabetically.

```
row = Row(foo=1, bar=2)
```

Then it creates an object like the following:

```
Row(bar=2, foo=1)
```

When I then create a dataframe on this object, the column order is going to be bar first, foo second, when I'd prefer to have it the other way around.

I know I can use "_1" and "_2" (for "foo" and "bar", respectively) and then assign a schema (with appropriate "foo" and "bar" names). But is there any way to prevent the Row object from ordering them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Spark >= 3.0**

Fields sorting has been removed with [SPARK-29748](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29748) (*Remove sorting of fields in PySpark SQL Row creation
Export*), with exception to legacy mode, when following environmental variable is set:

```
PYSPARK_ROW_FIELD_SORTING_ENABLED=true
```

**Spark < 3.0**

> But is there any way to prevent the Row object from ordering them?

There isn't. [If you provide `kwargs` arguments will sorted by name](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d83c2f9f0b08d6d5d369d9fae04cdb15448e7f0d/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L1202). Sorting is required for deterministic behavior, because Python before 3.6, doesn't preserve the order of the keyword arguments.

Just use plain tuples:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 2)])
```

and pass the schema as an argument to [`RDD.toDF`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788832/10465355) (not to be confused with [`DataFrame.toDF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.toDF)):

```
rdd.toDF(["foo", "bar"])
```

or `createDataFrame`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark.createDataFrame(rdd, ["foo", "bar"])

# With full schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("foo", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("bar", IntegerType(), False)])

spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

You can also use `namedtuples`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

FooBar = namedtuple("FooBar", ["foo", "bar"])
spark.createDataFrame([FooBar(foo=1, bar=2)])
```

Finally you can sort columns by `select`:

```
sc.parallelize([Row(foo=1, bar=2)]).toDF().select("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: What if I have a nested Row object?

Row(foo=(Row(foo1=1,bar1=2))

Comment: Use tuples and provide schema.

Comment: Okay. Thank you! That's what I'm currently doing. The only reason I ask is because I'm constructing a very complicated (nesting, arrays, etc) object. Was hoping there was a way to avoid creating a schema.

Comment: It is better to do it anyway. You save the time required for schema inference and avoid some categories of errors.

Comment: Passing a list of column names to toDF as in `RDD.toDF([list:str])` does not work for me on Spark 2.4.1. I have to `RDD.toDF().select(list:str)` which does work.

Comment: @rjurney Sounds like you confused the methods - `rdd.toDF` to [monkey patched `RDD.toDF`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788832/10465355), which [doesn't take varargs](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/eaa88ae5237b23fb7497838f3897a64641efe383/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L45-L58). You from the other hand, refer to [`DataFrame.toDF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.toDF), which indeed uses varargs, and doesn't support lists or sampling rate.

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row):

> Row also can be used to create another Row like class, then it could be used to create Row objects

In this case order of columns is saved:

```
>>> FooRow = Row('foo', 'bar')
>>> row = FooRow(1, 2)
>>> spark.createDataFrame([row]).dtypes
[('foo', 'bigint'), ('bar', 'bigint')]
```

Comment: But in that case you lose the ability to pass it named arguments. `FooRow(bar=2, foo=1)` will fail.

Answer (score 3):

How to sort your original schema to match the alphabetical order of the RDD:

```
schema_sorted = StructType()
structfield_list_sorted = sorted(df.schema, key=lambda x: x.name)
for item in structfield_list_sorted:
    schema_sorted.add(item)
```