# Something Wrong with Spark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I have a weird spark RDD, I am not sure what is wrong or how to go about troubleshooting. I am running Spark 1.6.2 with python 3.4.3 through an ipython notebook.

Here is how I am pulling in the data:

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
hdfs = 'hdfs://192.168.1.213:54310/TEMP/*' 

def make_Row(item):
    temp = {}
    if 'desc' in item:
        temp['desc']=str(item['desc']).lower()
    if 'cat' in item:
        temp['cat']= parse_cats(str(item['cat']).lower())
    if 'cat' in temp and 'desc' in temp:
        return Row(**temp)

raw_data = sc.wholeTextFiles(hdfs, 15).map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1])).flatMap(lambda x: x).map(lambda d: make_Row(d)).cache()
raw_data.count()
```

This brings me the count of the data:

Weird parts:

1. `raw_data.show()` gives the following exception. I checked ['PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'toDF' in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788387/pipelinedrdd-object-has-no-attribute-todf-in-pyspark), but I do have sqlContext defined.

   AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
    in ()
   ----> 1 raw_data.show()

   AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'show'
2. `raw_data.toDF().show()` works fine.
3. `raw_data.toDF().columns` shows: `['cat', 'desc']`, but `raw_data.toDF().describe('cat').show()` throws the following:

   ```
   Py4JJavaErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
       <ipython-input-110-45e3ce9b4e4b> in <module>()
       ----> 1 raw_data.toDF().describe('cat').show()

       /apps/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in describe(self, *cols)
           772         if len(cols) == 1 and isinstance(cols[0], list):
           773             cols = cols[0]
       --> 774         jdf = self._jdf.describe(self._jseq(cols))
           775         return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)
           776 

       /apps/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
           811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
           812         return_value = get_return_value(
       --> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
           814 
           815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

       /apps/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
            43     def deco(*a, **kw):
            44         try:
       ---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
            46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
            47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

       /apps/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
           306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
           307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
       --> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
           309             else:
           310                 raise Py4JError(

       Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1689.describe.
       : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 68.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 68.0 (TID 352, solrmain): java.lang.NullPointerException
           at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$$anonfun$toJavaArray$1.apply(SerDeUtil.scala:102)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.processCurrentSortedGroup(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:122)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.next(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:152)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.next(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:29)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:149)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

       Driver stacktrace:
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
           at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
           at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
           at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1383)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$describe$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1352)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$describe$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1335)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$withPlan(DataFrame.scala:2126)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.describe(DataFrame.scala:1335)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
           at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
           at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
           at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
           at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
           at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
           at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$$anonfun$toJavaArray$1.apply(SerDeUtil.scala:102)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.processCurrentSortedGroup(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:122)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.next(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:152)
           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.next(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:29)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
           at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:149)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
           ... 1 more
   ```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The RDD API does not have a `show()` method, hence the error in #1.  You need to either convert to a dataframe (as you do in #2) or use something like:

```
raw_data.take(5)
```

to get a list of your row objects.

Re #3, the toDF method is a little finicky depending on the distribution you're using.  Try this:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(raw_data)
```

then run your other operations.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 has already been answered: RDD does not have a `show()` method.

Number 3: Try  `raw_data.toDF().describe(['cat']).show()`