# Rename more than one column using withColumnRenamed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rename

I want to change names of two columns using spark withColumnRenamed function. Of course, I can write:

```py
data = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2), (3,4)], ['x1', 'x2'])
data = (data
       .withColumnRenamed('x1','x3')
       .withColumnRenamed('x2', 'x4'))
```

but I want to do this in one step (having list/tuple of new names). Unfortunately, neither this:

```py
data = data.withColumnRenamed(['x1', 'x2'], ['x3', 'x4'])
```

nor this:

```py
data = data.withColumnRenamed(('x1', 'x2'), ('x3', 'x4'))
```

is working. Is it possible to do this that way?

Comment: The accepted answer is efficient, but watch out for the other answers that suggest calling `withColumnRenamed` multiple times.  The `withColumnRenamed` approach should be avoided for [reasons outlined in this blog post](https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015).  See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

It is not possible to use a single `withColumnRenamed` call.

- You can use [`DataFrame.toDF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=todf#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF) method*

  ```py
  data.toDF('x3', 'x4')
  ```

  or

  ```py
  new_names = ['x3', 'x4']
  data.toDF(*new_names)
  ```
- It is also possible to rename with simple `select`:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql.functions import col

  mapping = dict(zip(['x1', 'x2'], ['x3', 'x4']))
  data.select([col(c).alias(mapping.get(c, c)) for c in data.columns])
  ```

Similarly in Scala you can:

- Rename all columns:

  ```scala
  val newNames = Seq("x3", "x4")

  data.toDF(newNames: _*)
  ```
- Rename from mapping with `select`:

  ```scala
  val  mapping = Map("x1" -> "x3", "x2" -> "x4")

  df.select(
    df.columns.map(c => df(c).alias(mapping.get(c).getOrElse(c))): _*
  )
  ```

  or `foldLeft` + `withColumnRenamed`

  ```scala
  mapping.foldLeft(data){
    case (data, (oldName, newName)) => data.withColumnRenamed(oldName, newName) 
  }
  ```

---

* Not to be confused with [`RDD.toDF`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788832/1560062) which is not a variadic functions, and takes column names as a list,

Comment: In your 3rd example `data.select([col(c).alias(mapping.get(c, c)) for c in data.columns])`: how would you write `data.columns` if you do method chaining (so something like col but referencing the dataframe?

Comment: Using `df.select` is the right way to do it in spark (scala/python). Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62728542/8551891

Answer (score 30):

I couldn't find an easy pyspark solution either, so just built my own one, similar to pandas' `df.rename(columns={'old_name_1':'new_name_1', 'old_name_2':'new_name_2'})`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def rename_columns(df, columns):
    if isinstance(columns, dict):
        return df.select(*[F.col(col_name).alias(columns.get(col_name, col_name)) for col_name in df.columns])
    else:
        raise ValueError("'columns' should be a dict, like {'old_name_1':'new_name_1', 'old_name_2':'new_name_2'}")
```

So your solution will look like `data = rename_columns(data, {'x1': 'x3', 'x2': 'x4'})`

If you want to chain your method calls, Spark 3.0 brought in [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform.html), which you can use in the following way:

```
my_df.transform(lambda df: rename_columns(df, {'old_name_1':'new_name_1', 'old_name_2':'new_name_2'}))
```

It saves me some lines of code, hope it will help you too.

Comment: Updated this response 3 years after, with a more efficient solution, after I had to fix performance of sooo many jobs using .withColumnRenamed() in a for loop. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 18):

why do you want to perform it in a single line
if you print the execution plan it is actually done in single line only

```
data = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2), (3,4)], ['x1', 'x2'])
data = (data
   .withColumnRenamed('x1','x3')
   .withColumnRenamed('x2', 'x4'))
data.explain()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [x1#1548L AS x3#1552L, x2#1549L AS x4#1555L]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[x1#1548L,x2#1549L]
```

if you want to do it with a tuple of list
you can use a simple map function

```
data = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2), (3,4)], ['x1', 'x2'])
new_names = [("x1","x3"),("x2","x4")]
data = data.select(list(
       map(lambda old,new:F.col(old).alias(new),*zip(*new_names))
       ))

data.explain()
```

still has same plan

**OUTPUT**

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [x1#1650L AS x3#1654L, x2#1651L AS x4#1655L]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[x1#1650L,x2#1651L]
```

Answer (score 13):

Since **pyspark 3.4.0**, you can use the [`withColumnsRenamed()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnsRenamed.html) method to rename multiple columns at once. It takes as an input a map of existing column names and the corresponding desired column names.

```py
df = df.withColumnsRenamed({
    "x1": "x3",
    "x2": "x4"
})
```

The method renames both columns at the same time. Note that if a column (e.g., `"x1"`) doesn't exist in current dataframe schema, no error is thrown. Instead, it is simply ignored.

Answer (score 10):

This should work if you want to rename multiple columns using the same column name with a prefix

```
df.select([f.col(c).alias(PREFIX + c) for c in df.columns])
```

Comment: You wrote `for c in columns` so not `df.columns` this gives me an error but it would be so useful if it worked (for method chaining). How did you make this work?

Comment: @corianne1234 For chaining and changing the column names use `transform` `df.transform(lambda df2: df2.select([col(acol).alias(acol + '_tmp') for acol in df2.columns]))`

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [Dictionary](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/)  to iterate through the columns you want to rename.

Sample:

```
a_dict = {'sum_gb': 'sum_mbUsed', 'number_call': 'sum_call_date'}

for key, value in a_dict.items():
    df= df.withColumnRenamed(value,key)
```

Answer (score 6):

I have this hack in all of my pyspark program:

```
import pyspark
def rename_sdf(df, mapper={}, **kwargs_mapper):
    ''' Rename column names of a dataframe
        mapper: a dict mapping from the old column names to new names
        Usage:
            df.rename({'old_col_name': 'new_col_name', 'old_col_name2': 'new_col_name2'})
            df.rename(old_col_name=new_col_name)
    '''
    for before, after in mapper.items():
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(before, after)
    for before, after in kwargs_mapper.items():
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(before, after)
    return df
pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.rename = rename_sdf
```

Now you can easily rename any spark dataframe in the pandas way!

```
df.rename({'old1':'new1', 'old2':'new2'})
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer by zero323 is efficient.  Most of the other answers should be avoided.

Here's another efficient solution that leverages the [quinn](https://github.com/MrPowers/quinn) library and is well suited for production codebases:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2), (3,4)], ['x1', 'x2'])
def rename_col(s):
    mapping = {'x1': 'x3', 'x2': 'x4'}
    return mapping[s]
actual_df = df.transform(quinn.with_columns_renamed(rename_col))
actual_df.show()
```

Here's the DataFrame that's outputted:

```
+---+---+
| x3| x4|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
```

Let's take a look at the logical plans that are outputted with `actual_df.explain(True)` and verify they're efficient:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project ['x1 AS x3#52, 'x2 AS x4#53]
+- LogicalRDD [x1#48L, x2#49L], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
x3: bigint, x4: bigint
Project [x1#48L AS x3#52L, x2#49L AS x4#53L]
+- LogicalRDD [x1#48L, x2#49L], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [x1#48L AS x3#52L, x2#49L AS x4#53L]
+- LogicalRDD [x1#48L, x2#49L], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [x1#48L AS x3#52L, x2#49L AS x4#53L]
```

The parsed logical plan and physical plan are basically equal, so Catalyst isn't doing any heavy lifting to optimize the plan.

Calling `withColumnRenamed` multiple times should be avoided because it creates an inefficient parsed plan that needs to be optimized.

Let's look at an unnecessarily complex parsed plan:

```py
def rename_columns(df, columns):
    for old_name, new_name in columns.items():
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(old_name, new_name)
    return df

def rename_col(s):
    mapping = {'x1': 'x3', 'x2': 'x4'}
    return mapping[s]
actual_df = rename_columns(df, {'x1': 'x3', 'x2': 'x4'})
actual_df.explain(True)
```

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Project [x3#52L, x2#49L AS x4#55L]
+- Project [x1#48L AS x3#52L, x2#49L]
   +- LogicalRDD [x1#48L, x2#49L], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
x3: bigint, x4: bigint
Project [x3#52L, x2#49L AS x4#55L]
+- Project [x1#48L AS x3#52L, x2#49L]
   +- LogicalRDD [x1#48L, x2#49L], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [x1#48L AS x3#52L, x2#49L AS x4#55L]
+- LogicalRDD [x1#48L, x2#49L], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [x1#48L AS x3#52L, x2#49L AS x4#55L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this function:

```
def spark_rename_from_dict(df, rename_dict):
    newcols = [rename_dict.get(i,i) for i in df.columns]
    df = df.toDF(*newcols)
```

Here your rename dict is a mapping over a subset of `df.columns`. This approach is recommended since it does not create multiple dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is as follows:

1. Get all columns in the pyspark dataframe using `df.columns`
2. Create a list looping through each column from step 1
3. The list will output: `col("col1").alias("col1_x")`.Do this only for the required columns
4. `*[list]` will unpack the list for select statement in pypsark

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
(df
 .select(*[F.col(c).alias(f"{c}_x") for c in df.columns])
 .toPandas().head()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.pandas_api().rename(columns=dict(x1="x3",x2="x4"))
```

out：

```
+---+---+
| x3| x4|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Requires pandas to be imported.

Comment: @Steven not pandas ,its pandas on spark api

Answer (score 0):

If you want change the name with de same text without convert to pandas, you can do this:

```
columns = df.columns
new_columns = {}
for n in range(len(columns)-1):
    new_columns.update(dict(zip([columns[n],columns[n+1]],[columns[n]+'_new',columns[n+1]+'_new'])))
df_rename = df.select([F.col(c).alias(new_columns.get(c, c)) for c in df.columns])
```