# Dynamically rename multiple columns in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, special-characters

I have a dataframe in pyspark which has 15 columns.

The column name are `id`, `name`, `emp.dno`, `emp.sal`, `state`, `emp.city`, `zip` .....

Now I want to replace the column names which have `'.'` in them to `'_'`

Like `'emp.dno'` to `'emp_dno'`

I would like to do it dynamically

How can I achieve that in pyspark?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use something similar to [this great solution from @zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38798692/5741205):

```
df.toDF(*(c.replace('.', '_') for c in df.columns))
```

alternatively:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

replacements = {c:c.replace('.','_') for c in df.columns if '.' in c}

df.select([col(c).alias(replacements.get(c, c)) for c in df.columns])
```

The `replacement` dictionary then would look like:

```
{'emp.city': 'emp_city', 'emp.dno': 'emp_dno', 'emp.sal': 'emp_sal'}
```

**UPDATE:**

> if I have dataframe with space in column names also how do replace
>   both `'.'` and space with `'_'`

```
import re

df.toDF(*(re.sub(r'[\.\s]+', '_', c) for c in df.columns))
```

Comment: @Virureddy, could you post an output of `print(df.columns)` as it is?

Comment: @Virureddy, thank you! And how does `print(replacements)` look like?

Comment: @Virureddy, please try this: `df.toDF([c.replace('.', '_') for c in df.columns])`

Comment: here is the output error pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.\nOld column names

Comment: @Virureddy, this is really strange... How can it differ?

Comment: does it matter that all columns need to have the special character because some columns are normal strings like id, tempo

Comment: @Virureddy, what do you mean, saying `need to have the special character`?

Comment: I mean to say .

Comment: `[c.replace('.', '_') for c in df.columns]` - should give you a list of desired column names

Comment: the query is replacing the . with _ but how can we specify to do this only when there is . present in column names if no . present leave column name a it is

Comment: @Virureddy, this exactly what `[c.replace('.', '_') for c in df.columns]` is doing

Comment: Looks like the number of columns in old dataframe are 124 but when we do the query it says number of columns is 1

Comment: @Virureddy, can you try this: `df.toDF(c.replace('.', '_') for c in df.columns)` or `df.toDF((c.replace('.', '_') for c in df.columns))` or `df.toDF(*(c.replace('.', '_') for c in df.columns))`

Comment: df.toDF(*(c.replace('.', '_') for c in df.columns)) this worked

Comment: Thank you Very much for the help and patience

Comment: @Virureddy, i don't have a PySpark environment at home, so i couldn't test it - that's the reason for all those failed attempts...

Comment: Really appreciate your patience and help

Comment: df.toDF(*(c.replace('.', '_') for c in df.columns)) in this we are replacing . with _  say if I have dataframe with space in column names also how do replace both . and space with _

Comment: could you please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710484/compare-schema-of-two-data-frames-in-pyspark-add-columns-if-not-existing

Comment: I was able to do this for both space and dot replacement (i removed if condition as well). you can also string together multiple replace() calls to take care of multiple character replacements, but if the amount of special characters to be replaced are too much then original poster's solution under "update" would work better as you can just add more characters to the regular expression pattern.

     `replacements = {c:c.replace('.','_').replace(' ','_') for c in df.columns}`

Comment: Using `df.select` is the right way to do it in spark (scala/python). Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62728542/8551891

Answer (score 6):

Wrote an easy & fast function for you to use. Enjoy! :)

```
def rename_cols(rename_df):
    for column in rename_df.columns:
        new_column = column.replace('.','_')
        rename_df = rename_df.withColumnRenamed(column, new_column)
    return rename_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is as follows:

Explanation:

1. Get all columns in the pyspark dataframe using df.columns
2. Create a list looping through each column from step 1
3. The list will output:col("col.1").alias(c.replace('.',"_").Do this only for the required columns. Replace function helps to replace any pattern. Also, you can exclude a few columns from being renamed
4. *[list] will unpack the list for select statement in pypsark

`from pyspark.sql import functions as F
(df
 .select(*[F.col(c).alias(c.replace('.',"_")) for c in df.columns])
 .toPandas().head()
)`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

MaxU's answer is good and efficient.  This post outlines another approach that's also efficient and helps keep your codebase clean (using the [quinn](https://github.com/MrPowers/quinn) library).

Suppose you have the following DataFrame:

```
+---+-----+--------+-------+
| id| name|emp.city|emp.sal|
+---+-----+--------+-------+
| 12|  bob|New York|     80|
| 99|alice| Atlanta|     90|
+---+-----+--------+-------+
```

Here's how you can replace the dots with underscores in all the columns.

```
import quinn

def dots_to_underscores(s):
    return s.replace('.', '_')
actual_df = df.transform(quinn.with_columns_renamed(dots_to_underscores))
actual_df.show()
```

Here's the resulting `actual_df`:

```
+---+-----+--------+-------+
| id| name|emp_city|emp_sal|
+---+-----+--------+-------+
| 12|  bob|New York|     80|
| 99|alice| Atlanta|     90|
+---+-----+--------+-------+
```

Let's use `explain()` to verify that this function is executing efficiently:

```py
actual_df.explain(True)
```

Here's the logical plans that are outputted:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project ['id AS id#50, 'name AS name#51, '`emp.city` AS emp_city#52, '`emp.sal` AS emp_sal#53]
+- LogicalRDD [id#29, name#30, emp.city#31, emp.sal#32], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: string, name: string, emp_city: string, emp_sal: string
Project [id#29 AS id#50, name#30 AS name#51, emp.city#31 AS emp_city#52, emp.sal#32 AS emp_sal#53]
+- LogicalRDD [id#29, name#30, emp.city#31, emp.sal#32], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [id#29, name#30, emp.city#31 AS emp_city#52, emp.sal#32 AS emp_sal#53]
+- LogicalRDD [id#29, name#30, emp.city#31, emp.sal#32], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [id#29, name#30, emp.city#31 AS emp_city#52, emp.sal#32 AS emp_sal#53]
```

You can see that the parsed logical plan is almost identical to the physical plan, so the Catalyst optimizer doesn't need to do much optimization work.  It's converting `id AS id#50` to `id#29`, but that's not too much work.

The `with_some_columns_renamed` method generates an even more efficient parsed plan.

```py
def dots_to_underscores(s):
    return s.replace('.', '_')
def change_col_name(s):
  return '.' in s
actual_df = df.transform(quinn.with_some_columns_renamed(dots_to_underscores, change_col_name))
actual_df.explain(True)
```

This parsed plan only aliases the columns with dots.

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [unresolvedalias('id, None), unresolvedalias('name, None), '`emp.city` AS emp_city#42, '`emp.sal` AS emp_sal#43]
+- LogicalRDD [id#34, name#35, emp.city#36, emp.sal#37], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: string, name: string, emp_city: string, emp_sal: string
Project [id#34, name#35, emp.city#36 AS emp_city#42, emp.sal#37 AS emp_sal#43]
+- LogicalRDD [id#34, name#35, emp.city#36, emp.sal#37], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [id#34, name#35, emp.city#36 AS emp_city#42, emp.sal#37 AS emp_sal#43]
+- LogicalRDD [id#34, name#35, emp.city#36, emp.sal#37], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [id#34, name#35, emp.city#36 AS emp_city#42, emp.sal#37 AS emp_sal#43]
```

More information why looping over the DataFrame and calling `withColumnRenamed` multiple times creates overly complex parsed plans and should be avoided.