# How to add suffix and prefix to all columns in python/pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in pyspark with more than 100 columns. What I want to do is for all the column names I would like to add back ticks(`) at the start of the column name and end of column name.

For example:

```
column name  is testing user. I want `testing user`
```

Is there a method to do this in pyspark/python. when we apply the code it should return a data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `withColumnRenamed` method of dataframe in combination with `na` to create new dataframe

```
df.na.withColumnRenamed('testing user', '`testing user`')
```

edit : suppose you have  list of columns, you can do like -

```
old = "First Last Age"
new = ["`"+field+"`" for field in old.split()]
df.rdd.toDF(new)
```

output :

```
DataFrame[`First`: string, `Last`: string, `Age`: string]
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: if you are just trying to export data from mysql to hive, you might as well just use sqoop , unless you are performing any specialized processing on data , you dont have to go thru spark.

Answer (score 40):

Use list comprehension in python.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = ...

df_new = df.select([F.col(c).alias("`"+c+"`") for c in df.columns])
```

This method also gives you the option to add custom python logic within the alias() function like: `"prefix_"+c+"_suffix" if c in list_of_cols_to_change else c`

Answer (score 8):

To add prefix or suffix:

1. Refer df.columns for list of columns ([col_1, col_2...]). This is the dataframe, for which we want to suffix/prefix column.

```py
df.columns
```

2. *Iterate* through above list and create another list of *columns with alias* that can used inside select expression.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

select_list = [col(col_name).alias("prefix_" + col_name)  for col_name in df.columns]
```

3. When using inside select, do not forget to ***unpack*** list with asterisk(*). We can assign it back to same or different df for use.

```py
df.select(*select_list).show()
df = df.select(*select_list)
```

df.columns will now return list of new columns(aliased).

Comment: Thanks for the steps-breakdown. Using `df.select` in combination with `pyspark.sql.functions` `col-method` is a reliable way to do this since it maintains the mapping/alias applied & thus the order/schema is maintained after the rename operations. Below is the sample `select_list` content:

`[Column<b'XYZ AS prefix_XYZ'>, Column<b'ABC_ID AS prefix_ABC_ID'>]`

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to add a prefix or suffix to multiple columns in a pyspark dataframe, you could use a for loop and .withColumnRenamed().

As an example, you might like:

```
def add_prefix(sdf, prefix):

      for c in sdf.columns:

          sdf = sdf.withColumnRenamed(c, '{}{}'.format(prefix, c))

      return sdf
```

You can amend sdf.columns as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

I had a dataframe that I duplicated twice then joined together. Since both had the same columns names I used :

```
df = reduce(lambda df, idx: df.withColumnRenamed(list(df.schema.names)[idx],
                                                 list(df.schema.names)[idx] + '_prec'),
            range(len(list(df.schema.names))),
            df)
```

Every columns in my dataframe then had the '_prec' suffix which allowed me to do sweet stuff

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how this answers the question?

Comment: The question asked was how to had a suffix or a prefix to all the columns of a dataframe. Here I added a suffix but you can do both by simply changing the second parameter of `withColumnRenamed`. In the person's case it would be `"'" + list(df.schema.names)[idx] + "'")`