# DataFrame' object has no attribute 'add_suffix'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
z= k.withColumn('date', when( k.date > 29, 1).otherwise(0)).collect()
```

i want to add suffix to the dataframe

```
z1 = k.add_suffix(19)
```

getting Error as

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'add_suffix'

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add a suffix to multiple columns in a pyspark dataframe, you could use a **for** loop and **.withColumnRenamed()**.

As an example, you might like:

```
def add_suffix(sdf, suffix):

      for c in sdf.columns:

            sdf = sdf.withColumnRenamed(c, '{}{}'.format(c, suffix))

      return sdf
```

You can amend sdf.columns as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

try with **.withColumnRenamed** function instead of add_suffix.

```
z1 = k.withColumnRenamed('date', 'date_19')
```

(or)

You can create a lambda function that can add suffix to all columnnames in data frame.

reference:-
[How to add suffix and prefix to all columns in python/pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160103/how-to-add-suffix-and-prefix-to-all-columns-in-python-pyspark-dataframe)