# Give prefix to all columns when selecting with 'struct_name.*'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

The dataframe below is a temp_table named: 'table_name'.
How would you use spark.sql() to give a prefix to all columns?

```
root
 |-- MAIN_COL: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- f: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- g: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- j: long (nullable = true)
```

The below query

```
spark.sql("select MAIN_COL.* from table_name")
```

gives back columns named a,b,c..., but how to make them all look like e.g. pre_a, pre_b, pre_c?
**Want to avoid selecting and giving them alias one by one. What if I have 30 columns?**

I hope a custom UDF can solve it which is used in SQL, but really not sure how to handle this.

```
 # Generate a pandas DataFrame
import pandas as pd
a_dict={
    'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'b':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'c':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'e':list('abcde'),
    'f':list('abcde'),
    'g':list('abcde')
}
pandas_df=pd.DataFrame(a_dict)
# Create a Spark DataFrame from a pandas DataFrame using Arrow
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

#struct
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct
main=df.select(struct(df.columns).alias("MAIN_COL"))
```

Comment: You can concate existing column name with string "pre_" and replace all the column name from select using the map function.

Comment: can you provide some rough data to test our approach?

Comment: @samkart what is the best way of it? You mean create a dataframe etc. so ppl just literally have to copy it in Jupyter?

Comment: anything works for us! We can even read from an url.

Comment: @samkart added edit with example dataset

Comment: @MaheshGupta  you mean the RDD map function?

Comment: Chris yes RDD map function to Create schema

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160103/how-to-add-suffix-and-prefix-to-all-columns-in-python-pyspark-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beauty of Spark, you can programatically manipulate metadata

This is an example that continues the original code snippet:

```
main.createOrReplaceTempView("table_name")

new_cols_select = ", ".join(["MAIN_COL." + col + " as pre_" + col for col in spark.sql("select MAIN_COL.* from table_name").columns])

new_df = spark.sql(f"select {new_cols_select} from table_name")
```

Due to Spark's laziness and because all the manipulations are metadata only, this code doesn't have almost any performance cost and will work same for 10 columns or 500 columns (we actually are doing something similar on 1k of columns).

It is also possible to get original column names in more elegant way with `df.schema` object

Comment: This will add extra overhead to the program. You are 1. creating a new temp table 2. execute a select query with spark.sql(...) 3. finally iterate through the columns. All these steps are not needed for just modifying the columns and changing their names. That you can achieve directly through `main.schema` as you already mentioned yourself. I think you can achieve the same just with the last point since in `main.schema` you have all the necessary  data

Comment: It should have been "createOrReplaceTempView", thanks. Apart from that, column iterations and sql statement adds just several milliseconds to overall execution. `main.schema` is useful,  but you still need to iterate over, and not enough for more complex operations, while this approach enables different kinds of field manipulations.

Comment: This couple of msec that you mentioned is arbitrary. It can be some msec in one system and a couple of hours in another one so for such a decision the performance is determining.  The expression `spark.sql("select MAIN_COL.* from table_name").columns` will force revaluation of the table `table_name` so that `createOrReplaceTempView` will be called and all the data will be transferred again in Spark memory. This constitutes an unnecessary overhead which you can easily avoid. As shown below no complex iterations are required, in fact just one is more than enough.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to go through the fields and modify their names dynamically. First use  `main.schema.fields[0].dataType.fields` to access the target fields. Next use python `map` to prepend `pre_` to each field:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

inner_fields = main.schema.fields[0].dataType.fields

# [StructField(a,LongType,true),
#  StructField(b,LongType,true),
#  StructField(c,LongType,true),
#  StructField(e,StringType,true),
#  StructField(f,StringType,true),
#  StructField(g,StringType,true)]

pre_cols = list(map(lambda sf: StructField(f"pre_{sf.name}", sf.dataType, sf.nullable), inner_fields))

new_schema = StructType(pre_cols)

main.select(col("MAIN_COL").cast(new_schema)).printSchema()

# root
#  |-- MAIN_COL: struct (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- pre_a: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- pre_b: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- pre_c: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- pre_e: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- pre_f: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- pre_g: string (nullable = true)
```

Finally, you can use `cast` with the new schema as @Mahesh already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this: add all the column as per requirements to schema2

```
val schema2 = new StructType()
    .add("pre_a",StringType)
    .add("pre_b",StringType)
    .add("pre_c",StringType)
```

Now select column using like:

```
df.select(col("MAIN_COL").cast(schema2)).show()
```

it will give you all the updated column names.

Comment: thanks Mahesh. What do you think, is there any scalable way? I might have many many columns in many diff situations, hardcoding only works for once :(

Comment: I think you can read that struct column using the function and then create the schema using map functions.

Answer (score 0):

The following **expands all the struct columns** adding the parent column name as prefix.

```py
struct_cols = [c for c, t in df.dtypes if t.startswith('struct')]
for c in struct_cols:
    schema = T.StructType([T.StructField(f"{c}_{f.name}", f.dataType, f.nullable) for f in df.schema[c].dataType.fields])
    df = df.withColumn(c, F.col(c).cast(schema))
df = df.select([f"{c}.*" if c in struct_cols else c for c in df.columns])
```

Test input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df = spark.createDataFrame([((1, 2), 5)], 'c1:struct<f1:int,f2:int>, c2:int')
print(df.dtypes)
# [('c1', 'struct<f1:int,f2:int>'), ('c2', 'int')]
```

Result:

```py
struct_cols = [c for c, t in df.dtypes if t.startswith('struct')]
for c in struct_cols:
    schema = T.StructType([T.StructField(f"{c}_{f.name}", f.dataType, f.nullable) for f in df.schema[c].dataType.fields])
    df = df.withColumn(c, F.col(c).cast(schema))
df = df.select([f"{c}.*" if c in struct_cols else c for c in df.columns])

print(df.dtypes)
# [('c1_f1', 'int'), ('c1_f2', 'int'), ('c2', 'int')]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also do this with PySpark:

```
df.select([col(col_name).alias('prefix' + col_name) for col_name in df])
```