# How to use fillna function with column having period in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, fillna

I tried to run fillna to insert nan in column with special character "."

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(None, None), ('U1', None), ('U3', 1.0)], 
    ['USER_ID', 'a.b']
)
```

I tried

```
df = df.fillna({"`a.b`": float("nan")})
```

also

```
df = df.fillna({"a.b": float("nan")})
```

Both of them doesn't work, who have experience on this?

Comment: Which version of spark?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a limitation of [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna) which doesn't allow you to specify column names with periods in them when you use the `value` parameter as a dictionary.

From the docs:

> **value** – int, long, float, string, bool or dict. Value to replace null values with. If the value is a dict, then *subset* is ignored and *value* must be a mapping from column name (string) to replacement value. The replacement value must be an int, long, float, boolean, or string.

You should be able to use `fillna` using the other syntax that specifies both the `value` and `subset` parameters.

```
df.fillna(value=float("nan"), subset=["a.b"]).show()
#+-------+---+
#|USER_ID|a.b|
#+-------+---+
#|   null|NaN|
#|     U1|NaN|
#|     U3|1.0|
#+-------+---+
```

The above worked for me in Spark 2.4, but I don't see why it should not work on older version.

If you are still having trouble, another way to do this would be to temporarily [rename your columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798567/pyspark-rename-more-than-one-column-using-withcolumnrenamed), call `fillna`, and then rename the columns back to the original values:

Here I will [rename the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44382252/5858851) to replace the `"."` with the string `"_DOT_"`, which I deliberately picked to avoid conflicting with existing substrings in other column names.

```
df.toDF(*[c.replace(".", "_DOT_") for c in df.columns])\
    .fillna({"a_DOT_b": float("nan")})\
    .toDF(*df.columns)\
    .show()
#+-------+---+
#|USER_ID|a.b|
#+-------+---+
#|   null|NaN|
#|     U1|NaN|
#|     U3|1.0|
#+-------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(None, None), ('U1', None), ('U3', 1.0)], ['USER_ID', 'a.b'])
df = df.fillna(float("nan"), ['`a.b`'])
df.show(10, False)

+-------+---+
|USER_ID|a.b|
+-------+---+
|null   |NaN|
|U1     |NaN|
|U3     |1.0|
+-------+---+
```

Comment: running in my notebook it still failed

Comment: An error was encountered:
u'Cannot resolve column name "a.b" among (USER_ID, a.b);'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1672, in fillna
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.na().fill(value, self._jseq(subset)), self.sql_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in

Comment: what version of spark and python?

Comment: Actually, it works once i tested it again. Thanks