# How to batch up items from a PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark data frame and for each (batch of) record(s), I want to call an API. So basically say I have 100000k records, I want to batch up items into groups of say 1000 and call an API. How can I do this with PySpark? Reason for the batching is because the API probably will not accept a huge chunk of data from a Big Data system.

I first thought of `LIMIT` but that wont be "deterministic". Furthermore it seems like it would be inefficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.foreachPartition { ele =>
   ele.grouped(1000).foreach { chunk =>
   postToServer(chunk)
}
```

Code is in scala, you can check same in python. It will create batches of 1000.

Comment: Just curious, isit better `repartition` to create partitions of desired sizes and just process the batches in a similar way (without the grouped) or is this better? If so why? Can I say repartition is too expensive in general? Also I find that the result is not a dataframe. How should I make it a dataframe? Theres https://stackoverflow.com/a/48111699/292291, but wonder if I can do without explicitly setting the column names in `toDF()`?

Comment: The ` repartition` algorithm does a full shuffle and creates new partitions with data that's distributed evenly. It is expensive, it gives parallelism to your application.

Comment: For some reason, now I get "'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'grouped'" any idea why? It seems like `itertools.chain`  indeed does not have the function grouped. I am using PySpark btw

Answer (score 3):

Using `foreachPartition` and then something like this [how to split an iterable in constant-size chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290397/how-to-split-an-iterable-in-constant-size-chunks) to batch the iterables to groups of 1000 is arguably the most efficient way to do it in terms of Spark resource usage.

```
def handle_iterator(it):
    # batch the iterable and call API
    pass
df.foreachPartition(handle_iterator)
```

Note: This would make parallel calls to the API from executors and might not be the way to go in practise if e.g. rate-limiting is an issue.

Comment: Is there no way to do the grouping in spark? Also if I am doing the chunking in Python, is there any reason of using foreachPartition over just map?

Comment: Map is lazy and should not contain any side-effects. It also accesses a single row at time so it is not suitable for batching. If you wanted to batch in spark, there is an aggregate function called `collect_list`. However, you'd need to figure out grouping/windowing that produces even 1k batches. For example with the mentioned 10^8 rows, you could group by hash modulo 10^5 which requires first calculating the df size and then almost certainly shuffling data.