# Grouping in Apache Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Apache Spark. Below is my Spark `dataframe` that is created when I read a csv file.

```
Parent  Keyword   Volume
P1       K1        100
P1       K2        200
P1       K3        150
P2       K4        100
P2       K5        200
```

I need to convert the above dataframe to the below one. The logic is for all the keywords that belong to the same parent are related and should be listed in the sorted order by Volume. As an example `K1, K2, K3` belong to the same parent `P1` so they all are related. So, for `K1`, related keywords are `K2` and `K3`. `K2` is displayed first because it's volume(`200`) is greater than `K3(150)`.

```
Keyword   Related_keywords
K1         K2, K3
K2         K3, K1
K3         K2, K1
K4         K5
K5         K4
```

I am new to Spark and looking at this problem, `groupBy` may be used but don't know exactly how to turn the first dataframe to second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this can be done using `groupBy`, window functions are usually easier when you need all the original rows in the result data frame. We can use `collect_list` but as the [doc says](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_list-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-), the order is nondeterministic so let's create tuples of volumes and keywords:

```
val txt =
  """Parent  Keyword   Volume
    |P1       K1        100
    |P1       K2        200
    |P1       K3        150
    |P2       K4        100
    |P2       K5        200""".stripMargin.lines
    .map(_.split("\\s+").mkString("|"))
    .toSeq
    .toDS()
val df = spark.read
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .option("header", true)
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .csv(txt)

val win = Window.partitionBy($"Parent")
val df1 =
  df.select($"Keyword",
            collect_list(struct(-$"Volume", $"Keyword")).over(win) as "rel")
```

Now we almost have the desired format

```
df1.select(array_sort($"rel") as "Related_keywords")
  .show(20, false)
```

Output:

```
+------------------------------------+
|Related_keywords                    |
+------------------------------------+
|[[-200, K5], [-100, K4]]            |
|[[-200, K5], [-100, K4]]            |
|[[-200, K2], [-150, K3], [-100, K1]]|
|[[-200, K2], [-150, K3], [-100, K1]]|
|[[-200, K2], [-150, K3], [-100, K1]]|
+------------------------------------+
```

However, there are two issues, the original `Keyword` would be duplicated in the list and there is the negative volume in front of all keywords. To make this prettier, I believe UDF:s are needed (could not find a SQL function for unzipping the tuples):

```
val myudf = udf(
  (keyword: String, rel: Seq[Row]) =>
    rel
      .collect {
        case Row(volume: Int, kw: String) if kw != keyword => (volume, kw)
      }
      .sortBy(_._1)
      .map(_._2))

df1.select($"Keyword", myudf($"Keyword", $"rel") as "Related_keywords")
  .show(20, false)
```

Output:

```
+-------+----------------+
|Keyword|Related_keywords|
+-------+----------------+
|K4     |[K5]            |
|K5     |[K4]            |
|K1     |[K2, K3]        |
|K2     |[K3, K1]        |
|K3     |[K2, K1]        |
+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks.. that worked. One more thing I need to do is to create a JSON out of the result dataframe and then call an HTTP POST request to send. I can call collect() but the issue is the output dataframe could contain millions of rows so calling collect might give Out of memory issue on driver. So how should I proceed about it?

Comment: If you want to call the API for each entry separately `df.toJSON.foreach(jsonStr => callApi(jsonStr))` or if you need to batch it `df.toJSON.foreachPartition` like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979027/how-to-batch-up-items-from-a-pyspark-dataframe/55979908#55979908